# Get CloudFormation stack output from client environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We're working on creating a CloudFormation stack which will be published to clients to install an "on-prem" agent of our product on a client's AWS environment.
We want to initiate the connection from our end and add some configurations based on the outputs of the CloudFormation.

Is there a way to automatically transmit the output of CloudFormation back to the publisher of the template? I've been looking for a solution online but with no avail. Not sure this is possible - but I'm hoping someone here has maybe done something similar.

Couldn't find any solution. From what I'm seeing the "only" way to do so is to ask the client to manually send back the output, but I'm glad to be proven wrong  :)

Comment: Are you looking to get information about the resources created by CloudFormation after the template is installed? As in, you want it to phone home somewhere?

Comment: @A.R.Younce - yes, exactly! What I'm actually aiming at is creating IAM role, and once it's created - send a notification back to our env that the role is created and usable

Comment: See my answer below. I've not been able to find an example in the AWS docs of what the messages CloudFormation posts to SNS look like, but I will try to find an example from my own work and will update my answer with it if an official example can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

So I happen to be working on something similar, and this is what I've found that works. There are caveats which I will enumerate.

**TLDR;**

To have a CloudFormation stack "phone home" you can specify a SNS topic that the stack will post changes to when it is created, updates, and/or deleted. The [CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-add-tags.html) (see 'Notification options') and [CLI reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html) (see '--notification-arns') mention this. You can then have a Lambda respond to the SNS messages to enable your desired behavior. Unfortunately you cannot specify this topic in the stack template and can only provide is when making the call to create the stack. This can be worked around by using a [nested CloudFormation stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html).

**My (current) approach:**

1. Use a SNS topic that has a [resource policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/security-iam.html#security_iam_access-manage) which allows the installing user's AWS account to publish messages to your topic. [AWS documents how to do this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-access-policy-use-cases.html#sns-grant-aws-account-access-to-topic), but be warned that using a [AWS Account Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-accounts) in the SNS topic policy (which so far is the only thing that has worked for *me*) allows **anything** in the customer account to publish to the SNS topic. This security issue is one part I have yet to work around and ideally a combination of a [Service Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-services) and restrictive IAM policy conditions could be used instead.
2. Create a template that you provide to your user that acts as the top-level stack, and contains a nested stack which you will use to create resources in your user's AWS account. This also gives you an opportunity to do things like [use a mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html) that specifies per-region SNS topics for your CloudFormation notifications.
3. When [specifying your nested stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#aws-properties-stack-properties) in your top-level stack template you use the `NotificationARNs` property to provide the SNS topic ARN so that the nested stack will report back to you.
4. The Lambda (or other mechanism) that subscribes to the SNS topic will need to parse and filter the messages that CloudFormation posts to react appropriately. When needing to acquire the ARN of something like an IAM role in the user's AWS account my recommendation would be to give the role a static name such that you can know the role's ARN by using the user's AWS account ID and the role name. Ideally the role will have permission to retrieve information about the CloudFormation stack so that you can get ARNs and other data about any other resources your stack created.